# DatePicker android - changing day from 31 to 1 also change the month (+1)

Tags: android, react-native, datepicker

I'm using react-native-datetimepicker to include a native datepicker in my app.

With iOS all works good, but I have some problems with the android version... 
If I change the day from 31 to 1, also the month will change (example: from 31 **January** to 01 **February**). 
The same thing happens with the years (January **2020** --> december **2019**)

I'm using the "spinner" datepicker.

[image: this is the datepicker i'm using]

There's a way to do it? or simply this is a native android behaviour?